# How to update SQL on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have two tables. T1 is completely filled and looks like this:

```
ean | id | title | price |
```

T2 looks the same, but has missing records. It contains the id's of T1. So what I wanna do, is fill in the empty records with T1's data on T1.id = T2.id.

I looked up my question on stackoverflow and came up with this code:

```
UPDATE monitoren 
SET T2.ean = T1.ean 
FROM T2
JOIN T1
ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

(Of course I also wanna update the columns title and price in T2.)

This gives me a syntax error at '`FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id`'

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support a `FROM` clause.  Instead, you express the join like this:

```
UPDATE T2 JOIN
       T1
       ON T1.id = T2.id
    SET T2.ean = T1.ean ;
```